# jasmine - spy property into jquery.post callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

With Jasmine. I'm trying to assert if a property changed after a **`$.post`**, I mean in it's callback.

```
$.post(x,x,function(){
   boolean = true;            <--- need to assert this
})
```

Because I don't really want my tests to be coupled to $ I can spyOn, something like.

```
spyOn($,'post')
```

This works BUT I'm overwriting my original callback and my boolean will never be change.

I could use ".CallThrough" but I don't want the REALLY do the post, it's a test.

Any idea how to solve it?
I'm thinking it wrong ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I would go another way from :

```
$.post(x,x,function(){
   boolean = true;            <--- need to assert this
});
```

to :

```
function callback(){
    boolean = true;
}

$.post(x,x,callback)
```

And test only callback.